# Configure WebVR in google chrome mobile for specific google cardboard / VR device

Tags: google-chrome, google-cardboard, aframe, webvr

I've created a simple WebVR app using A-Frame. On my phone it will launch into VR mode however it doesn't seem to be well configured for my model of google cardboard. The two images are two far apart and I just get a double vision rather than 3d effect.

I can get a good VR experience on the google cardboard app by configuring cardboard to the specific model of google cardboard. Is there an equivalent that can be done in google chrome to tell it the model of cardboard I'm using / display distance etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this issue thread on GitHub:
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2117

The solution toward the bottom from *garrethwilliams* explains what you can do to tweak A-Frame to work with your model of the phone until the *webvr-pollyfill* is updated with specs from the newer Android devices.